# WAMP Server won't allow me to visit php files

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have tried some of the techniques on the other questions here to no avail.  For some reason, after 3 weeks of no use, yesterday when I turned my laptop on and activated WAMP server (with no apparent problems, all visual feedback was ok), I am unable to visit any php files in my browser. I can go to `localhost/random.html`, but I cannot visit `localhost/otherfile.php`. I have no idea what the problem could be, no configuration has changed since I last used it.  I have installed windows updates, I am using Windows XP, but I can't find any indication.  The php error log is empty, and the apache error log is not showing me any concrete errors (though I have looked up what it is showing) that led me to a solution.

Any ideas on what to do or where to look for a solution?

Comment: are ALL the WAMP services running? in particular the php one? if the apache one is running, that'd probably let you go to html files but not php files, as they need processing.

Comment: @Shane.C I can see how to manage the apache and mysql services, how do I look at the status of the php service?

Comment: For starters, if you click "restart all services" does the WAMP icon go full green? I thought there may have been a service too, but it looks like there's only one for apache and mysql

Comment: Yeah, it goes all green.  As I said there are no indications of an issue except that I can't load any php pages.

Comment: Backup WWW folder from WAMP directory. Reinstall your WAMP and replace your backup files that is replace WWW folder. Giving the solution for this kind of problem without seeing your system is complex. Reinstall takes only few minutes. So i am suggest you to reinstall your WAMP.

Comment: Have you edit config file of APACHE ?